# Replacing values in prototype: class static getters, or class fields?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class, ecmascript-next

Years ago, I wrote my own "declare" implementation that mimicked Dojo's (anyone?): https://github.com/mercmobily/simpleDeclare  This is now made obsolete by `class`. The beauty of SimpleDeclare is that I could do this:

```
// Basic definition of the managers store
var Managers = declare( JsonRestStores, JsonRestStores.HTTPMixin, JsonRestStores.SimpleDbLayerMixin, {

  schema: new Schema({
    name   : { type: 'string', trim: 60 },
    surname: { type: 'string', searchable: true, trim: 60 },
  }),

  storeName: 'managers',
  publicURL: '/managers/:id',

  handlePut: true,
  handlePost: true,
  handleGet: true,
  handleGetQuery: true,
  handleDelete: true,
});
var managers = new Managers();
```

Yes, it had multiple inheritance; and yes, things like `handePut`, `handlePost`, etc. were placed in a "middle-man" prototype.
Having to convert this code to ES6, I Have two options:
(Let's not cover "mixins" for now...)

## OPTION 1: static getters (which will end up as Managers.***):

```
// Basic definition of the managers store
class Managers extends JsonRestStores {

  static get schema() { return new Schema({
    name   : { type: 'string', trim: 60 },
    surname: { type: 'string', searchable: true, trim: 60 },
  }),

  static get storeName() { return 'managers' }
  static get publicURL() { return '/managers/:id' }

  static get handlePut() { return true }
  static get handlePost() { return true }
  static get handleGet() { return true }
  static get handleGetQuery() { return true }
  static get handleDelete() { return true }
};
var managers = new Managers()
```

## OPTION 2: class fields when they land (which will end up as normal object attributes when constructed):

```
// Basic definition of the managers store
class Managers extends JsonRestStores {

  schema = new Schema({
    name   : { type: 'string', trim: 60 },
    surname: { type: 'string', searchable: true, trim: 60 },
  })

  storeName = 'managers'
  publicURL = '/managers/:id'

  handlePut = true
  handlePost = true
  handleGet = true
  handleGetQuery = true
  handleDelete = true
};
var managers = new Managers()
```

The problem is that neither of these solutions really work as well as prototypes; having those values in the prototype gave 1) Defaults 2) The ability to an instance to find out what the parent's values were (e.g. manager.constructor.prototype). 3) The ability for an instance to *change* those values (this can be useful at times)

If I use `static get`, I get something that is  quite verbose, with the upside that an instance can figure out the values of the parent, and parent's parent, is; and, unless I create setters for each one, I can't modify those values either

If I use class fields (which don't even exist yet), I get better syntax, with the *major* downside that an instance can't figure out what the earlier defaults were (since all values are in the instance)

What would you do?

Comment: You should use a class constructor as an alternative to OPTION 2, your properties would still end up as normal object attributes, but that works with current es6 class implementations.

Comment: Class syntax comes with pitfalls, handling multiple inheritance would be especially a nightmare. Eric Elliot's [posts](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/3-different-kinds-of-prototypal-inheritance-es6-edition-32d777fa16c9) and [stampit library](https://github.com/stampit-org/stampit) are very interesting on this subject.

Comment: You mean, assigning the properties in the constructor one by one?

Comment: re: multiple inheritance, I am using Polymer's pattern to make mixins https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-elements#defining-mixins Although yes, having multiple inheritance was better :D

Comment: "*This is now made obsolete by `class`*" - I don't see why. Your syntax is obviously more appropriate. And it does work. So just keep it! What makes you think you're "*having to convert this code to ES6*"?

Comment: Because that's where the world is going. There are too many (half-)self-baked inheritance out there, mine being one of them. Javascript offers a kick-ass way of doing inheritance -- FINALLY, after YEARS -- so... let's all use it. Really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 creates new `Schema` instance each time the property is accessed, which is inadmissible overhead, unless this is desirable behaviour.

Option 2 creates new `Schema` instance for each `Managers` instance. If `Managers` is subclassed and `schema` is overridden, `Schema` will be instantiated any way, which provides overhead.

If all `Managers` instances are supposed to share same `schema` instance, it should be assigned to class prototype:

```
Managers.prototype.schema = new Schema(...);
```

It can also be defined as static property and be optionally doubled with a getter to provide easier access on class instance.

In ES.next:

```
class Managers extends JsonRestStores {
  static schema = new Schema(...);

  get schema() {
    return this.constructor.schema;
  }
  ...
}
```

In ES6:

```
class Managers extends JsonRestStores {      
  get schema() {
    return this.constructor.schema;
  }
  ...
}

Managers.schema = new Schema(...);
```

Comment: `class Managers extends JsonRestStores { static schema = new Schema(...)` is not valid Javascript -- I wish it were

Comment: Both [static](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) and [instance](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) class fields are stage 2 proposals. You used `schema = ...` class field in the question and put `ecmascript-next` tag on it. If you don't transpile code with Babel but rely on native implementation, class fields are not applicable, but it's unclear why you're targeting ES.next features in the question then. ES6 equivalent of static class field is `Managers.schema = new Schema(...)`.